Permission Issue Running a Shell Script Inside Docker Entrypoint
As I understand it, I should be able to run a shell script upon creating a container by copying it to the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory through my Dockerfile.
The issue I have is after running docker compose up, I receive the following error -
mysql_container-1  | 2024-12-16 21:14:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/shell.sh                                                     
mysql_container-1  | touch: cannot touch '/mysql_server/test': Permission denied

I had expected the shell script to run and create a file named test. Confusingly, I have been able to remove this script from my Dockerfile and exec into the container and touch a file without issue.
I had also tried to add RUN ["chmod", "u+x", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/shell.sh"] to my Dockerfile to no avail. Please see my docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile and shell.sh files below.
TIA for any help or guidance on this.
Dockerfile:
FROM mysql:lts
WORKDIR /mysql_server

COPY shell.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN ["chmod", "u+x", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/shell.sh"]

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  mysql_container:
    image: mysql_image:Dockerfile
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=docker_db

shell.sh:
#!/bin/sh
touch /mysql_server/test


u+x controls whether the script can start at all, it doesn't change what the script can do after it starts. Your problem is permissions on either the /mysql_server directory or any preexisting /mysql_server/test file, not on the db_init.sh file.

First and foremost, good practice for a Docker container running a database server is to have the actual data stored in a volume -- is that the case for the container here? If so, what are the file permissions for the volume itself? (Because docker enters a new UID namespace where user IDs inside the container can be different from the ones outside it, there's a fair bit that goes into answering that question -- you'll want to look from both directions)

...one place to start might to be to edit your shell script and add ls -lR /mysql_server; whoami before the touch command, just to start to get some of the basics. Again, chmod on the script isn't expected to make any difference at all, because the fact that you got an error from touch means that touch was successfully started, so there's no problem with permissions to start the script (which is the only kind of problem that the chmod you ran would fix).

Regarding your comment asking about data stored within a volume, I'm still very green and need to spend time understanding volumes, I don't have an answer on what permissions the volume itself has.

@CharlesDuffy thanks a ton for your help with this. To start, my Dockerfile had the line RUN ["chmod", "u+x", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh", that was a typo and it shouldve been shell.sh instead of db_init.sh, sorry about that - has since been edited.
Your suggestion to use ls -lR /mysql_server; whoami was great and showed root owned the folder. I was able to modify my Dockerfile to initially set the USER as mysql user to set the WORKDIR and copy the shell script and then set it as root after that was done. Definitely a folder permissions issue. Thanks again!

The mysql image's entrypoint script contains this fragment:
# If container is started as root user, restart as dedicated mysql user
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    mysql_note "Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'"
    exec gosu mysql "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
fi

So when it runs the scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, it's as the mysql user, if the user hasn't started the container as some other user.
You can in principle work around this by changing the directory's owner ship to match
# In the Dockerfile
RUN chown mysql /mysql_server

However, the important thing about the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory is that it only runs the very first time the container runs on a given MySQL data volume.  If the volume is already initialized then the entrypoint setup scripts won't run.  If you run the container twice, your file won't be there the second time
docker volume create mysql_data
docker run -v mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql mysql_image:Dockerfile ls -l
docker run -v mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql mysql_image:Dockerfile ls -l

Also remember that a container only runs a single process, and it's hard to access a container's filesystem from elsewhere.  Whatever files this script creates, you may have trouble actually accessing or using them.

Your suggestion to change ownership of the folder to the mysql user is much more elegant thank my workaround of starting the Dockerfile with USER mysql to establish its ownership over the folder then switching back to USER root later in the Dockerfile when that was done.
